# TCP/IP socket cannot establish a secure connection with TLSv1_2_client_method()

Tags: ssl, encryption, openssl, x509certificate

OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0g

Dev: lib libssl1.0-dev

Lang: C++

I have a client / server TCP socket application (C++, Linux). I have generated a self-signed certificate and both the client and the server are using the same certificate file (client and server are running on the same box).

To create certificate I run this command:

openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 2048

openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt

1/
When I implement SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_method())
the connection works and data can be transported, when using the cipher list: "ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH"

2/
When I use the code: SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_2_client_method())
The connection is not established and I get SSL_ERROR_SSL.

If I change the cipher list to "DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384", which should work with TLS, it doesn’t help. I get the same error.

3/
When I run: openssl s_client -connect x.x.x.x:yy, while the server is running the version with SSLv23_method(), I get the following:

...
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is AES256-GCM-SHA384

Server public key is 2048 bit

Secure Renegotiation IS supported

Compression: NONE

Expansion: NONE

No ALPN negotiated

SSL-Session:

```
Protocol  : TLSv1.2

Cipher    : AES256-GCM-SHA384
```

...

**My question is:**

A/ I want to be able to use the method = TLSv1_2_client_method(). Do I need to generate certificates with different command parameters?

B/ Why the openssl s_client in the case 3/ is using the protocol TLSv1.2, when the server protocol was defined with the method =  SSLv23_method() ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting it. Are you trying to create a server implementation with the method `TLSv1_2_client_method()`? This is not clear from the question. Furthermore, `SSLv23_method` and related methods *have been deprecated*; I presume they simply forward to `TLSv1_2_method` until they get removed altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Using EC cipher requires that a curve will be selected (for example by calling SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(ctx, 1);). I was missing this call.

@Maarten Bodewes: yes, I wanted to use TLSv1_2_method, but they were failing. SSL method were working (while not using EC cipher). With solution above the TLSv1_2_method is working with EC ciphers.